# How to change the publishing date of each posts?

Tags: posts, admin, database, wp-admin, mysql

I need to set the publishing date of many posts with the post date (the creation date).

I know that I can do it editing the single post and changing the **Published on** value but this procedure is problematic if I have some hundreds of posts

Exist some clean way to do it or have I to changing these value on the database (using PhpMyAdmin) avoiding to editing each post?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the publish date for hundreds of posts then your best bet without a plugin or homemade solution is through a MySQL query.